# Modify Solr default field by config file or API

Tags: solr

I am looking for a way to change df. I found many files named solrconfig.xml, and changed the df properties there, but it had no effect.

Solr version is 6.4.

Comment: Did you reload the core/collection after changing the value? Are you using Solr in standalone mode?

Comment: yes, I reloaded the core after changing the value. I use solr in SolrCloud mode.

Comment: If you're using cloud mode, those configuration files are stored in zookeeper and not in the usual location on disk

Comment: ok, @MatsLindh, and then is there any way to set df?

Comment: You can set `df` in the request handler configuration in solrconfig (now located inside zookeeper). I usually recommend doing it in your query library from the client, but if you want to share the configuration across many applications, doing it in the request handler configuration is preferred.